# How to send/copy data in edit text to another activity

Tags: android, android-edittext, send

> Blockquote

**pleas help me, i have activity aaa, bbb and ccc, in activity aaa i have data edittext, can i send data edittext from aaa to ccc?, but activity aaa intent to bbb and bbb intent to ccc**

> Blockquote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you reached the data of "aaa" edittext, you can create a variable that equals to what is in the edittext.

Then, you can use SharedPreferences to save the variable into a key, and then use this key on an other activity.

Create a variable named a , a==your edittext text.

then use this code to save "a" into a key:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    score = prefs.getInt("key", a);
```

and then at the other activity use this code to get "a":

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     int value = prefs.getInt("key", 0);
```

Comment: txtMeja = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.No_Meja);
  txtQuota = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Quota);
  SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     String score = prefs.getInt("key", txtMeja);  getInt error? how to solve?

Comment: You need first to get a variable named "a" and make a be equal to what typed inside the edit text.. and then use my code.. or you can use intents as other told.

Answer (score 0):

use putExtra to pass arguments between activities:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ccc.class);
intent.putExtra("EDIT_TEXT_DATA", editText.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: but activity aaa to bbb, and bbb to ccc, can send from aaa to ccc?

Comment: then pass it from aaa to bbb and from bbb to ccc

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using intents, do like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ccc.class);
intent.putExtra("data from edittext", editText.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in ccc class do this;

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

String dataFromaaa = intent.getStringExtra("data");
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to reference your `EditText` and get the text :

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.my_edit_text);
String theText = et.getText().toString();
```

then pass it to another `Activity`,  you use an `Intent`. for example :

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyNewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("text_label", theText);
startActivity(i);
```

In the new Activity in (`onCreate()`), you get the Intent and retrieve the String, for example :

```
public class MyNewActivity extends Activity {

    String string1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(...) {

        ...

        Intent i = getIntent();
        string1= i.getStringExtra("text_label");

    }
}
```